# SwiftUI change reading speed

Tags: avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I need help with a problem I'm having with my SwiftUI project.
I have a button created to change the reading speed, but when I press it, the speed changes correctly, but the reading starts from the beginning and I don't understand how to solve it

```
func startReading() {
        if let document = pdfDocument {
            let pageCount = document.pageCount
            var documentContent = ""
            for pageIndex in 0..<pageCount {
                if let page = document.page(at: pageIndex),
                   let pageContent = page.string {
                    documentContent.append(pageContent)
                }
            }
            
            if synthesizer.isSpeaking {
                synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
            }
            
            // Assign the utterance to the instance variable
            utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: documentContent)
            utterance?.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate * Float(CGFloat(speeds[speedIndex])) / 2.0
            synthesizer.speak(utterance!)
        }
    }
    
    func increaseSpeed() {
        if synthesizer.isSpeaking {
            synthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        }
        speedIndex = (speedIndex + 1) % speeds.count
        if isPlaying {
            // Update the rate of the utterance with the new speed
            utterance?.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceMaximumSpeechRate * Float(CGFloat(speeds[speedIndex])) / 2.0
            startReading()
        }
    }
```

I would like it to change the speed when I press the button but without returning to the beginning, whether it is in play (changing in real time) or if it is paused (when I press Play again the reading resumes from the point where it had started left before pausing it but with the speed changed)

Comment: There isn't any SwiftUI here. If the issue really does come from the intersection of SwiftUI and what you've listed (like where these actions are stored, what happens on button press, etc), you should include that code in a [mre]